# Can't access nested object in an immtable object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs

Try access Array in object. Write this to show all list

```
render() {
    var elems = this.props.items.course_list;
    console.log(elems);
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

Show that:

[image]

When I write this

```
render() {
    var elems = this.props.items.course_list;
    console.log(elems.course_list);
    return (
      <div>

      </div>
    )
  }


}
```

and try display **course list** object I get Cannot read property 'course_list' of undefined. Why I can't access to course_list ????

Comment: it should work. please try again and see if you have any other outputs from possible multiple re-renders

Comment: elems2 is already course list object.

Comment: please look last screen

Comment: How to access to it?

Comment: please screenshot `console.log(elems2)`

Comment: @Azola first image in post

Answer (score 4):

You assigned `elems2` to `elems.course_list`. Thus, `elems2` does not have that property but it is that property

**Update**: I am not getting error when I convert your JSON string to an Object, see;

[image]

Comment: What @Azola has stated is correct, you are accessing elemns.course_list.course_list.

Comment: @Alan yes, I need access this   console.log(elems.course_list.course_list); but I get undefined

Comment: try `console.log(elems.course_list[0].course_list);`

Comment: Is it possible that course_list[i].course_list isn't defined. Have you defined a course_list for each object of course_list?

Comment: @Alan How to define it? what you mean? now get this code `var elems = this.props.items;
       
        console.log(elems.course_list[0].course_list);`

Comment: Did that work? If it did it means that the array of object, course_list each has an object course_list. If not it probably means when you've created course_list the object doesn't have a member course_list within it.

Comment: do you have a sample JSON? @ЕгорКротенко

Comment: @Azola, no this data return server, I update post, again mimize code...

Comment: I am inclined to believe that course_list[i].course_list doesn't exist. Without any more data I have no other conclusion to go to. I am sorry.

Comment: @Azola `{"course_list":[{"course_id":1,"name":"Early childhood Piano lessons","created_at":"2016-12-01","remark":"","mark_delete":"1","course_state":4,"income_amount":0,"income_currency":""},{"course_id":2,"name":"Intermediate Piano Course","created_at":"2016-11-30","remark":"","mark_delete":"1","course_state":2,"income_amount":0,"income_currency":""},{"course_id":3,"name":"Advanced Piano Course","created_at":"2016-12-19","remark":"","mark_delete":"0","course_state":2,"income_amount":0,"income_currency":""}],"count":3}`

Comment: @Azola try parse and get Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: @Azola `var elems = this.props.items.course_list;
        var elems2 =  JSON.stringify(elems);
        var elems3 = JSON.parse(elems2);
        console.log(elems3);`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that elemns in itself is not initialized properly i.e. it is null. Try checking the output of elemns first.

Comment: please look last screen I udpate post

Comment: Yes, but in the second instance you are trying to access course_list of course_list, i.e. you are doing elemns.course_list.course_list. What you want to do is just elemns2=elemns.course_list, console.log(elemns2).

Comment: how to access elemns.course_list.course_list ? I need access this

Comment: console.log(elems.course_list.course_list); need to show that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```html
var elems2.course_list = elems.course_list;
console.log(elems2.course_list);
```

Or even this:

```html
var course_list = elems.course_list;
console.log(this.course_list);
```

Comment: please look last screen course_list have another course_list inside